# How can I get a window by clicking on a mapsubject in the QGIS web client?

Tags: qgis-web-client

Is it possible in Qgis-web-client to show a new little window (with custom informations and maybe a little picture) by clicking on a mapsubject? How to modify Qgis-web-client if possible?
Maybe its possible to modify the attribute-window, that i get on the right side by using the identification cursor-mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Aragon for your answer. My problem is still to find the right js-file. I tried all javascript files.

I have pasted code-examples which i found in the internet with no success...

Answer (score 0):

i think it is possible with adding some code into a javascript file (i dont know which is proper but you can find main js file wtih checking them all.) under qgis-web-client / site / js  then add this code:

```
map.events.register("click", map , function(e){
var opx = map.getLayerPxFromViewPortPx(e.xy) ;
alert(opx);// You can change this with adding window.
});
```

qgis-web-client is using extjs and openlayers background that you change everything If you have a little familiarity.

i hope it helps you...